# Why android MonkeyRunner can't connect remote android device

Tags: android, testing, monkeyrunner

Now, i'm studying how to use the **MonkeyRunner** to test android devices in the win7, now i have downloaded the latest android sdk, and configured all of the env
    There is an android4.4.2 tv set that enabled adbd, no usb debug port, but **network** is available. I can use a following commend to connect this device with adb in my pc:

```
adb connect 172.30.198.240.
```

Then i saw following print in my command window:
**List of devices attached

172.30.198.240:5555    device**
Checked this connection that was successful. we can use "***adb shell***" command to login the tv system shell.
i wrote a python script(called test.py) to test the MonkeyRunner.
**from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection() # <---can't connect device

if device is not None:

    device.takeSnapshot()**
after aboves done, i input the **"monkeyrunner.bat test.py"** in the win7 command window.
the codes blocked at the **MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()** for ever, and adb server was killed.
I have tried many ways, but all of them were failed.
**Try1**:
input **monkeyrunner.bat -s 172.30.198.240 test.py**, but failed again.
**Try2**:
i googled this issue, someone said we must set the adb port to **12345**, so, i changed the adb default port from 5555 to 12345 by using **adb tcpip 12345**,
failed again.
**Try3**:modify the script, add parameters for the waitForConnection method

```
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(5, "172.30.198.240:5555")
```

i got a nullpointer error for the device.
But if i use a phone with a usb debug port to connect my pc, above script ran ok.
I don't know why, could you help me?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) that could connect to devices connected over the network (i.e. TV) with no problems.

If you want to just take screenshots `dump -f` (one of the tools included in the package) does just that.

### NOTE:

There's also a typo in your snippet: **MokeyRunner** (missing **n**), but I guess you don't have it in your real code or you'll be receiving an exception.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but i don't want to use other tools to replace the monkeyrunner. So, i want to know the root cause why the monkeyrunner can't work in network environment. if monkeyrunner doesn't support the network connection, i will give up this tool and choose another tool.

Comment: I mentioned it because is almost a *drop-in* replacement

Comment: I have submitted this question to the google android group. Till now, no one reply to me... This tool is developed by google, there should be no such obvious problem.